# A question on definable categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, lo.logic, set-theory

One way to define a category set-theoretically might be to give four $\in$-formulas (not sets!)

$$\begin{array}{rl}
\mathsf{O}(X)&\text{(“$X$ is an object”)}\\
\mathsf{M}(X,Y,z)&\text{(“$z$ is a morphism from $X$ to $Y$”)}\\
\mathsf{C}(x,y,z)&\text{(“$z$ is a composition of $x$ and $y$”)}\\
\mathsf{I}(X,y)&\text{(“$y$ is an identity of $X$”)}
\end{array}$$

for which [some formulas (“axioms”)](http://epublius.de/Axioms_for_definable_categories.html) are provable from the axioms of set theory. The ingredients of a thus definable category $\mathcal{C}$ will be given (not necessarily as sets) by

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\operatorname{Obj}(\mathcal{C})&:\equiv&\lbrace X\ :\ \mathsf{O}(X) \rbrace\\
\operatorname{Mor}(\mathcal{C})&:\equiv&\lbrace (X,Y,z)\ :\ \mathsf{M}(X,Y,z)\rbrace\\
\operatorname{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(X,Y)&:\equiv&\lbrace f\ :\ (\exists z)\ f = (X,Y,z) \wedge \mathsf{M}(X,Y,z)\rbrace
\end{array}$$

The “axioms” include some sort of typing axioms:

$$\begin{array}{rcll}
\mathsf{M}(X,Y,z)&\rightarrow&\mathsf{M}_1(X,Y)&\\
\mathsf{C}(x,y,z)&\rightarrow&\mathsf{C}_1(x,y,z)&\\
\mathsf{I}(X,y)&\rightarrow&\mathsf{I}_1(X,y)&
\end{array}$$

with the typing conditions

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\mathsf{M}_1(X,Y)&:\equiv&\mathsf{O}(X)\ \wedge\ \mathsf{O}(Y)\\
&&\text{(“morphisms are from objects to objects”)}\\
\mathsf{C}_1(x,y,z)&:\equiv&(\exists X,Y,Z)\ \ \mathsf{M}(X,Y,x)\ \wedge\ \mathsf{M}(Y,Z,y)\ \wedge\ \mathsf{M}(X,Z,z)\\
&&\text{(“only morphisms between appropriate objects can be composed”)}\\
\mathsf{I}_1(X,y)&:\equiv&\mathsf{M}(X,X,y)\\
&&\text{(“identities are morphisms from an object $X$ to itself”)}\\
\end{array}$$

Looking at [some examples](http://epublius.de/Examples_of_definable_categories.html) and thinking of other definable categories I know, I get the impression that the typing conditions are often either explicitly built-in in the formulas $\mathsf{M}, \mathsf{C}, \mathsf{I}$ (e.g. $\mathsf{C} :\equiv \mathsf{C}_1 \wedge \mathsf{C}'$) or the typing axioms hold otherwise tautologically (e.g. $\mathsf{M} \equiv \mathsf{M}_1 \wedge \mathsf{M}'$), i.e. hold independently of the axioms of set theory.

> I am looking for an example of a category $\mathcal{C}$ definable by formulas
>   $\mathsf{O}, \mathsf{M}, \mathsf{C}, \mathsf{I}$ as above, fulfilling the
>   “axioms”, for which the typing axioms are *not* fulfilled tautologically, i.e. require the axioms of set theory.

Comment: What is your motivation?  It is trivial to construct an artificial example.

Comment: I'd like to understand better those "(set-theoretically) definable categories" - and this is one of the first questions I stumbled upon. And even though I'm also interested in your trivial artificial example, I am more interested in "natural" examples.

Comment: Artificial example: Objects are groups, and morphisms are isomorphisms from a group (or rather its underlying monoid) to a monoid.

Comment: But morphisms have to be from objects to objects?